# extract host name from url using apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

For example,

```
 url: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html
 url: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html
```

URL is not just limited to the above examples. I would want to extract host name as:

```
 host_name : pig.apache.org
```

Could any one help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually looking to extract host names, not domain names. `pig.apache.org` is a host name, `apache.org` is the domain name.

Luckily the nice people at Pig have written a UDF to do this. Simply use the Host Extractor UDF as such:

```
host = FOREACH row GENERATE org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.util.apachelogparser.HostExtractor(referer);
```

The API docs can be found at:
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/util/apachelogparser/HostExtractor.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are trying to do is run a regex on each url to extract the hostname.  This should be something like :

`splt = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'.*\://(?:www.)?([^\/]+)',1))`